# Regarding Feynman Integration - unnamed theorem (?)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, compactness

I found a certain theorem, that hasn't been proven in the article and as it seems to require just Calculus 2 (multivariable calculus) knowledge.- I would like to prove it, however I am completely stuck how to approach this problem.

Therefore I would be very happy, if someone could provide any sort of constructive hint, comment or answer or recommendation for further reading. As always thanks in advance.

The theorem states as follows:

Let $ f : [a, b]×Y → \mathbb{R} $ be a function,
with $ [a, b]$ being a closed interval, and Y being a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose that both $f(x, y)$ and $\frac{∂}{∂x}f(x, y)$ are continuous in the variables $x$ and $y$ jointly.

Then $ \int_Y f(x, y)dy$ exists as a continuously differentiable function of $x$ on $[a, b]$ with:

$\frac{d}{dx} \int_Y f(x, y)dy = \int_Y \frac {∂}{∂x} f(x, y)dy $

Comment: Somehow compactness allows to switch around the order of: integration over Y and building the limit in x - (differentiation is just a limit), but dunno, how to pinpoint my thoughts

Comment: is this not some kind of lebesgue dominated convergence theorem? Just because differentiation is $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{x}$?

Comment: I agree, I just looked up "Dominated convergence theorem" and it looks good so far. I don't understand the details yet, but I will look further into it! Thx!

Comment: In fact it seems: There is a whole cluster of theorems regarding summation, integration/derivation allowing switching around operations under certain conditions. So interesting..

Comment: This is called Leibniz's Rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @Chappers, great !!